# Does making a variable a const or final save bytes or memory?

Tags: c, variables, constants, final

I've been working with a program and I've been trying to conserve bytes and storage space.

I have many variables in my C program, but I wondered if I could reduce the program's size by making some of the variables that [don't change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) throughout the program `const` or `final`.

So my questions are these:

- Is there any byte save when identifying static variables as `constant`?
- If bytes are saved by doing this, why are they saved? How does the program store the variable differently if it is `constant`, and why does this way need less storage space?
- If bytes are not saved by defining variables as `constant`, then why would a developer define a variable this way in the first place? Could we not just leave out the `const` just in case we need to change the variable later (especially if there is no downfall in doing so)?
- Are there only some IDEs/Languages that save bytes with `constant` variables?

Thanks for any help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the compiler optimizes it as a compile-time constant then yes it could save a few bytes of memory since it might not need space for the variable. That requires you to initialize the variable on definition, and that you never ever anywhere takes the address of the variable. But in general, don't count on it.

Comment: As for why people uses `const`? Well if you have a variable that is not allowed to be modified, then of course we make it `const`. It's a semantic thing, it helps when people read the code, it helps against you (or someone else) making stupid mistakes, and it might even help the compiler when it makes decision about optimizations.

Comment: C does not specify `constant`.  It does specify `const`.

Comment: Depending on the processor, a constant variable might end up as an immediate value operand of an instruction, and this could save a small amount of space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your questions depend heavily on compiler and environment. A C compiler intended for embedded environment can do a great job about saving memory, while others maybe not.

> Is there any byte save when identifying static variables as constant?

Yes, it may be possible. But note that "const", generally, isn't intended to specify how to store a variable - instead its meaning is to help the programmer and the compiler to better understand the source code (when the compiler "understand better", it can produce better object code). Some compiler can use that information to also store the variable in read-only memory, or delete it and turn it into literals in object code. But in the context of your question, may be that a `#define` is more suitable.

> If bytes are saved by doing this, why are they saved? How does the program store the variable differently if it is constant, and why does this way need less storage space?

Variables declared in source code can go to different places in the object code, and different places when an object file is loaded in memory and executed. Note that, again, there are differences on various architectures - for example in a small 8/16 bits MCU (cpu for electronic devices), generally there is no "loading" of an object file. So the value of a variable is stored somewhere - anyway. But at low level the compiler can use literals instead of addresses, and this mostly saves some memory. Suppose you declare a constant variable GAIN=5 in source code. When that variable is used in some formula, the compiler emits something like "LD R12,GAIN" (loads register R12 with the content of the address GAIN, where variable GAIN is stored). But the compiler can also emit "LD R12,#5" (loads the value "5" in R12). In both cases an instruction is needed, but in the second case there is no memory for variables involved. This is a saving, and can also be faster.

> If bytes are not saved by defining variables as constant, then why would a developer define a variable this way in the first place? Could we not just leave out the const just in case we need to change the variable later (especially if there is no downfall in doing so)?

As told earlier, the "const" keyword is meant to better define what operations will be done on the variable. This is useful for programmers, for clarity. It is useful to clearly state that a variable is not intended to be modified, especially when the variable is a formal parameter. In some environments, there is actually some read-only memory that can only be read and not written to and, if a variable (maybe a "system variable") is marked as "const", all is clear to the programmer -and- the compiler, which can warn if it encounters code trying to modify that variable.

> Are there only some IDEs/Languages that save bytes with constant variables?

Definitely yes. But don't talk about IDEs: they are only editors. And about languages, things are complicated: it depends entirely on implementation and optimization. Likely this kind of saving is used only in compilers (not interpreters), and depends a lot on optimization options/capabilities of the compiler.

Answer (score 7):

I presume you're working on deeply embedded system (like cortex-M processors).
For these, you know that SRAM is a scarce resource whereas you have plenty of FLASH memory.
Then as much as you can, use the **const** keyword for any variable that doesn't change. **Doing this will tell compiler to store the variable in FLASH memory and not in SRAM.**

For example, to store a text on your system you can do this:

```
const char* const txtMenuRoot[] = { "Hello, this is the root menu", "Another text" };
```

Then not only the text is stored in FLASH, but also its pointer.

Comment: This answer tells a truth but is wrong: there is NO "memory saving", it simply uses a different kind of memory.

Comment: Where on my answer It is written that I save memory?

Comment: The question is about saving memory. Your answer should reply to the question, but it does not.

Answer (score 3):

Think of `const` this way (there is no such thing as `final` or `constant` in C, so I'll just ignore that). If it's possible for the compiler to save memory, it will (especially when you compile optimizing for size). `const` gives the compiler more information about the properties of an object. The compiler can make smarter decisions when it has more information and it doesn't prevent the compiler from making the exact same decision as before it had that information.

It can't hurt and may help and it also helps the programmers working with the code to easier reason about it. Both the compiler and the programmer are helped, no one gets hurt. It's a win-win.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers can reduce the memory used based on the knowledge of the code, const help compiler to know the real code behaviour (if you activate warnings you can have suggestions of where to put const).

But a struct can contains unused byte due to alignment restrictions of the hw used and compilers cannot alter the inner order of a struct. This can be done only changing the code.

```
struct wide               struct compact
{                         {
    int_least32_t i1;             int_least32_t i1,
    int_least8_t b;                             i2;
    int_least32_t i2;             int_least8_t b;
}                         }
```

Due to the alignment restrictions the struct wide can have an empty space between members 'b' and 'i2'.
This is not the case in struct compact because the elements are listed from the widest, which can require greater alignments, to the smaller.

In same cases the struct compact leads even to faster code.